# How to get ONLY columns with NA values and the amount of NAs

Tags: r

I have a dataset and some of the columns have NA values. I need to display only the column names that have NA values as well as the total number of NA values in each of those columns. 
I've been able to get different pieces of the problem working but not both things at once.

This gives me only the column names of the columns containing NA values. But I want the NA totals to show under each column name.

```
nacol<- colnames(df)[colSums(is.na(df)) > 0]
```

This gives me exactly what I want but it also displays the zero totals of the other columns in the dataframe and I don't want those to be displayed.

```
df %>% summarise_all(funs(sum(is.na(.))))
```

I'm obviously a complete beginner. I realize this is an extremely easy problem to fix but I've been trying for hours and I'm just getting frustrated. Please help. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `Filter` with `colSums` to remove 0 values

```
Filter(function(x) x > 0, colSums(is.na(df)))
#a c 
#2 1
```

Or `select_if` in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  summarise_all(~(sum(is.na(.)))) %>%
  select_if(. > 0)
```

---

We can also first select column with `any` `NA` values and then count them.

```
df %>%
  select_if(~any(is.na(.))) %>%
  summarise_all(~(sum(is.na(.))))
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(2, 3, NA, NA, 1), b = 1:5, c = c(1, 3, 4, NA, 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible alternative using `purrr` and `dplyr` for the pipe(using airquality for reproducibilty):

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

airquality %>% 
  keep(~anyNA(.x)) %>% 
   map_dbl(~sum(is.na(.x)))
  Ozone Solar.R 
     37       7
```

Using data from @Ronak Shah 's answer:

```
 df %>% 
  keep(~anyNA(.x)) %>% 
   map_dbl(~sum(is.na(.x)))
a c 
2 1
```

Using `data.table`(there might be a way to make it more compact):

```
setDT(df)
 df[,Filter(anyNA,.SD)][,lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))]
   a c
1: 2 1
```

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(a = c(2, 3, NA, NA, 1), b = 1:5, c = c(1, 3, 4, 
NA, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

airquality is builtin
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do

```
na.omit(na_if(colSums(is.na(df)), 0))
# a c 
# 2 1
```

---

Or using `summarise_if`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    summarise_if(~ any(is.na(.)), ~sum(is.na(.)))
#  a c
#1 2 1
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(2, 3, NA, NA, 1), b = 1:5, c = c(1, 3, 4, NA, 1))
```